# Create a Remotely Accessible File Objective C

Tags: objective-c, shell, terminal

I apologise if this question is a little broad but I cannot find a good starting point.

I am trying to create an app of OSX which will allow the user to browse the contents a specific folder remotely similar to the Plex Media Server or Dropbox (I know Dropbox transfers files to a server but you get my point). I know the Mac needs some serious configuration to get this to work for security reasons but where would one start with something like this?

Again any suggestions would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the folder located?

Comment: Users home directory